# Не полностью выносится за пределы цикла

Tags: javascript, циклы

Нужно вынести **template_list** за пределы цикла.
Сейчас он вынесен, но `$('#test').append(template_list);` почему-то выводит последний элемент массива [2, 'Вторая категория'], но нужно вывести все элементы и **именно за пределом цикла**.

Пример на jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kedQ7/1/

```
select = function(list) {
 template_list = '';

 for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var key = list[i][0];
  var value = list[i][1];
  var template_list = key+' '+value;
 }

 $('#test').html(template_list);
}

new select([[0, '- Не выбрано -'], [1, 'Первая категория'], [2, 'Вторая категория']])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select = function(list) {
 template_list = '';

 for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var key = list[i][0];
  var value = list[i][1];
  template_list += key+' '+value;
 }

 $('#test').append(template_list);
}

new select([[0, '- Не выбрано -'], [1, 'Первая категория'], [2, 'Вторая категория']])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kedQ7/2/

Обратите внимание на переменную template_list, которую вы объявили у себя до цикла, и по ошибке еще раз объявили в самом цикле..

Comment: @stasQa, спасибо огромное!